# SAP B1IF Variable from a previos SQL Call always comes blank despite it has a value

Tags: integration, sapb1

I'm quite new on B1IF and I have this strange problem that I'm sure that you guys could help me on this:

I'm working on a Scenario step where I need to do SQL Call and then put that result into a variable to use it in another SQL Call. When I do a XSL transformation this is working and printing the correct value:

```
<vDocFROMSAPCardCode>
<xsl:value-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom9']/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row/jdbc:CardCode"></xsl:value-of>
</vDocFROMSAPCardCode2>
```

This will print the value, However if I try to assign this to a Local Variable called vFROMSAPCardCode:

```
/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom20']/vDocFROMSAPCardCode2
```

Always comes empty. I need to use the result of that query in another query but always comes blank, despite the logic seams to be OK.

```
SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."DocEntry", T0."CardCode", T0."NumAtCard"  FROM ORDR T0 WHERE T0."CardCode" =  '$vFROMSAPCardCode'
```

Does anyone know what am I missing here? Or how to use the result of a previous query into antoher one?

BTW.

atom9 Is the original query that it's working fine

atom20 is the XSL transformation after the query is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to a variable in the xslt, declare the variable and assign the value in the 'select' attribute:

```
<xsl:variable name="vFROMSAPCardCode" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id=&apos;atom9&apos;]/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row/jdbc:CardCode"></xsl:variable>
```

You can also use the value in another qry directly by putting the 'xsl:value-of' instead of the variable (It can be done in xslt atom and then you can put the xPath in the sql call like [AquaVitale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7562724/aquavitale) answered)

```
SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."DocEntry", T0."CardCode", T0."NumAtCard"  FROM ORDR T0 WHERE T0."CardCode" =
<xsl:value-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id=&apos;atom9&apos;]/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row/jdbc:CardCode"></xsl:value-of>
```

(If you need to rap the value as string use the `&apos;` instead of ' )

Answer (score 0):

You can write your SQL Query in an XSL transformation Atom and then refer to it in your SQL Atom.

XSL transformation Atom:

```
<query>
SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."DocEntry", T0."CardCode", T0."NumAtCard"  FROM ORDR T0 WHERE T0."CardCode" =  '$vFROMSAPCardCode' 
</query>
```

And then in you SQL Call in the Payload field refer to the query Tag:

```
//vpf:Payload[./@id='atomX']//query
```